# Cannot find debugging information when debugging c++ dll

Tags: c#, c++, dll, debug-information

there:
The Application is build from C#, and the Dll is built from C++, and they are in different solution. When I Launch the Dll's debugger, there is always a message box pop up, which says "Debugging information for 'App.exe' cannot be found or does not match.Skipped loading symbols for NGen binary."

Thanks.

p.s. I've try putting the App.pdb in several location, but still don't work.

Comment: You have to re-build the `dll` *with* debug information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented by [ortang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/540286/ortang), you need to activate the debug info when building your project.

See "[`/DEBUG` (Generate Debug Info) (Visual Studio 2013)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe4t6fc1.aspx)":

> The `/DEBUG` option creates debugging information for the .exe file or DLL.
>
> The linker puts the debugging information into a program database (`PDB`). It updates the `PDB` during subsequent builds of the program.
>
> It is not possible to create an `.exe` or `.dll` that contains debug information.
>   Debug information is always placed in a `.pdb` file.
>   To set this linker option in the Visual Studio development environment
>
> - Open the project's `Property Pages` dialog box. For details, see [Setting Visual C++ Project Properties.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/669zx6zc.aspx)
> - Click the `Linker` folder.
> - Click the `Debugging property` page.
> - Modify the `Generate Debug Info` property.